# Scalable cloud solution for startup web application

Tags: php, mysql, cloud, scalable

I am running a startup and we are developing a web application for football addicted users (developed in PHP Laravel + MySql). As MVP, we plan to have 1000 users subscribed in the first year and lets say 500 of them can use the app at the same time. Most of the operations are database related (CRUD operations on database) and media management.

I am planning to develop the application in a scalable way. So one cloud server is used for the application (with load balancing) and the database and another server will act as CDN for media content (as a CDN).

My questions are: what cloud service (at a reasonable prices, being this a startup) shall I use in order to easy scale when we go above 1000 users? what kind of minimum resources do you think I would need at the beginning?

Thanks